# gRPC override remote-addr attribute before sending request

Tags: java, grpc

I have a fairly weird use case where I want to override the attribute `Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR` on the client side before sending my request.

On the server side, I receive the requests from many clients and extract their origins using this attribute. I then add  the origin to a cache to maintain a state on the server until the cache expires.

Now I want to do some load tests of the server side, and I want to start many clients on the same host to do that. I have tried starting these clients in docker containers, but the `remote-addr` attribute when the request reaches the server is always that of the external ip of the machine where the container is running, meaning it is not unique and will be treated that way by the server.

Here's how I get the origin ip on the server:

```java
@Override
public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
                                                             final Metadata headers,
                                                             final ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

    if (call.getAttributes().get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR) != null) {
        final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = (InetSocketAddress) call.getAttributes().get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR);
        if (remoteAddress == null) {
            throw DeviceModuleException.create(null,"Could not get remote address of grpc client");
        }
        final Context context = Context.current().withValue(ORIGIN_IP, remoteAddress.getHostName());
        return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
    }
    return next.startCall(call, headers);
}
```

And here's what I've tried to do on the client side:

```java
return BaseApiGrpc.newBlockingStub(NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(BRIDGE_HOST, BRIDGE_DEVICE_MODULE_PORT)
        .sslContext(buildSslContext())
        .intercept(new ClientInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
                return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<>(next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
                    @Override
                    public Attributes getAttributes() {
                        return Attributes.newBuilder()
                                .setAll(super.getAttributes())
                                .set(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR, new InetSocketAddress("fakeip", 1337))
                                .set(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_LOCAL_ADDR, new InetSocketAddress("fakeip", 1337))
                                .build();
                    }
                };
            }
        })
        .build());
```

However, the server still only receives the actual IP of the host I'm on. I'm guessing there are interceptors applied later than my interceptor and that overrides the `remote-addr` attribute.

But how could I achieve this? Will it break stuff?

I do not want to make any exceptions or special solutions on the server side, I would like that untouched if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attributes` are not transmitted between the client and server. The gRPC library does not call `ClientCall.getAttributes()`; it implements it. So your interceptor is changing the value but only your application has a chance to see the different value.

But that's actually mostly what you want! The only problem is you should use a `ServerInterceptor` instead of a `ClientInterceptor`! You should also make sure this new interceptor is executed *before* your existing `ServerInterceptor` that copies the remote IP to the `ORIGIN_IP` Context key.

```
class FakeAddressInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
            MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
        return new ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<>(next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
            @Override
            public Attributes getAttributes() {
                return super.getAttributes().toBuilder()
                        .set(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR, new InetSocketAddress("fakeip", 1337))
                        .set(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_LOCAL_ADDR, new InetSocketAddress("fakeip", 1337))
                        .build();
            }
        };
    }
}
...
// Your existing interceptor
serverBuilder.interceptor(new OriginIpContextInterceptor());
// Later interceptors are "nearer" the network, as they wrap your
// service, not the library
serverBuilder.interceptor(new FakeAddressInterceptor());
```